# I can't find any reference materials to create a hand tracking app, so I would appreciate it if you could provide a sample

Tags: hololens

I want to make a hand tracking app, but do you have any reference materials?

I expected some sammple program to help me make a hand tracking app.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the **[Mixed Reality Toolkit Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/example-scenes/hand-interaction-examples?view=mrtkunity-2022-05)** package via the **[Microsoft Mixed Reality Feature Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/welcome-to-mr-feature-tool#download)**, which has some official examples for hand tracking. It is recommended that you also refer to [Hand tracking - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2022-05). If this is not what you want, please be specific about your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I would like to get an app that can be used immediately and a sample program of the app.

Comment: MR examples imported from [Mixed Reality Toolkit Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/example-scenes/hand-interaction-examples?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) tutorials are all out-of-box working samples. Please try to run those samples and feel free to let me know if you have any questions. 
Otherwise, would you share more details of ‘a sample program of the app’?